# Why does sudo behave like this when the command has a variable assignment and what can I do?

Tags: bash, centos, centos5

I'm debugging a bash script and I have boiled down my problem to this very simple script. It runs in CentOS 5.7:

```
# tmp.sh
function do_as_someuser {
  sudo -u someuser -i "$1"
}

do_as_someuser "ls -l"       # line 1
#do_as_someuser "A=1 ls -l"  # line 2
```

When I execute this script uncommenting line 1 only, it shows the listing of the home directory of `someuser`, as expected:

```
[root@centos57 test]# ./tmp.sh 
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 someuser someuser 4096 Mar 14 23:36 some_dir
[root@centos57 test]#
```

But when I uncomment line 2 only, it logs me as `someuser` and doesn't go back to my user prompt, definitely not what I expected. Why should defining a variable make any difference after all?

```
[root@centos57 test]# ./tmp.sh 
[someuser@centos57 ~]$
```

`A=1 ls -l` runs perfectly fine when I write it directly in the command line. If this is a valid command, surely I should be able to execute it passing it as a parameter to `sudo`, shouldn't I?

My questions:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I modify `do_as_someuser` so it will execute a command that has a variable assignment?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what's happening is that `sudo` itself is interpreting the form "var=value" as an environment variable assignment, as opposed to just passing it through to the shell. As far as `sudo` is concerned, you're assigning `A` to have value `1 ls -l` and then not running a command. E.g., here's a quick console session:

```
$ sudo -i "X=5 ls"
root# echo $X
5 ls
```

Based on a quick test you can avoid the problem by using the `--` option immediately before the command you want to run:

```
$ sudo -i -- "X=5 ls"
... files ...
$ sudo -i -- 'BLORT=zorch env' | grep BLORT
BLORT=zorch
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/sh -c BLORT=zorch env
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you want is to use

```
sudo -u someuser $SHELL -c "A=1; ls -l; echo \$A"
```

i.e. putting the assignment of the variable you want to shuttle into the other user context at the beginning of the *shell command* you execute as that user.

A bit more readable alternative proving the point:

```
sudo -u someuser $SHELL -c "FOOBAR=BAZ env|grep FOOBAR"
```

Why does this happen? I think it happens because `sudo` isn't executing your given command using a shell as intermediary. This is what the command I gave above does, however. From the error message with `-i` I'd assume that `bash` (or in any case the login shell from `passwd`) is trying to `exec(3)` the command and not splitting the arguments - and frankly how would it know how to split it properly anyway?:

```
$ sudo -u someuser $SHELL -i "FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR"
bash: FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR: No such file or directory
```

But I believe the man page of `sudo` is wrong about the implementation in that case (documentation of the `-i` option):

> If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's `-c` option.

As you can see the above isn't exactly convenient because of the use of the variable which has to be escaped.

To stay with your example:

```
# tmp.sh
function do_as_someuser {
    sudo -u someuser $SHELL -c "$1"
}

do_as_someuser "ls -l"       # line 1
do_as_someuser "A=1 ls -l"   # line 2
```

---

The part I don't understand from your question is why you insist on using `-i` when you expect the command to be run and to return ... why the *initial login* shell then?
Do you require something from `.profile` et. al.?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Regarding `-i`, your observation is correct, it wasn't needed. It's interesting to note that my original example without `-i` gives a syntax error when using line 2, even though `sudo -u user command` should be valid in principle.

Comment: Also, I'm confused by your example `$ sudo -u someuser $SHELL -i "FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR"`, since you would be passing the `-i` option to `$SHELL`, not to sudo.

Comment: @Jong Bor Lee: correct and in case of `bash` the `-i` has a certain meaning. Of course it is somewhat wrong to assume that `$SHELL` will evaluate to `bash`.

Comment: I think that `$ sudo -u someuser $SHELL -i "FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR"` fails, not because it won't be parsed correctly as you say, but because what it does is executing `$SHELL` passing the option `-i` (interactive in most shells) and a script file name "FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR" which doesn't exist. So I'm not sure your explanation follows from this example... (or maybe I'm misreading what you meant...)

Comment: @Jong Bor Lee: concerning this exact example it's to the point what I wrote: *From the error message with -i I'd assume that bash (or in any case the login shell from passwd) is trying to exec(3) the command and not splitting the arguments - and frankly how would it know how to split it properly anyway?*

Comment: I think what happens in your example is simpler. Bash receives a filename as a parameter, not a command, so it says "Not such file or directory" when it is passed `"FOOBAR=1 env|grep FOOBAR"` as an argument.

Comment: @Jong Bor Lee: uhm, yep. That's what the quoted part says. If you pass it to a shell instead of passing it as the file argument to `exec(3)` you end up with the situation described, which is contrary to the documentation in `man sudo` but fits the observed behavior.